# ¿Como unir tablas en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo tres tablas relacionadas de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero hacer es que el resultado final quede de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la consulta SQL que hice fue la siguiente:

```
select pe.id_pago_empleado,e.nombre,e.apellido_paterno,e.apellido_materno,pe.sueldo,pe.frecuencia_pago,p.puesto
from empleado as e inner join pago_empleado as pe on e.id_empleado = pe.id_empleado
inner join puesto_empleado as p on p.id_puesto_empleado = e.id_puesto 
where e.estado = 'Activo' order by e.nombre asc;
```

Aun teniendo registros en la base de datos que cumplan con esa condicion no me arroja datos la consulta. Pero si solo relaciono dos tablas por ejemplo `empleado` y `pago_empleado` o `empleado` y `puesto_empleado` si me muestra registros.
La verdad soy muy nuevo en esto espero que me puedan ayudar gracias.

Comment: ¿Existe algún empleado que se encuentre tanto en la tabla `empleado` como en `pago_empleado`, que tenga un valor en la columna `id_puesto` y que su estado sea `"Activo"`? Si alguna de las condiciones no se cumple no vas a obtener el resultado esperado.

Comment: Si de echo ese era el error tenia un campo null por eso no me arrojaba registros la consulta. Gracias igual por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día.

Te comento que en lo personal parto de la tabla que me devuelve el universo de datos deseado; para tu caso (asumo) es **empleado**; es decir:

```
 /* El "as" no es obligatorio para asignar el alias */
SELECT EP.ID_EMPLEADO, EP.NOMBRE, EP.APELLIDO_PATERNO, EP.APELLIDO_MATERNO FROM EMPLEADO EP;
```

Ahora bien requerimos el puesto tambien; quedaría:

```
/* En alias para los campos si uso el "as" :D */
SELECT EP.ID_EMPLEADO, EP.NOMBRE, EP.APELLIDO_PATERNO, EP.APELLIDO_MATERNO, 
PE.NOMBRE AS PUESTO
FROM EMPLEADO EP
INNER JOIN PUESTO_EMPLEADO PE ON PE.id_puesto_empleado = EP.id_puesto;
```

Ahora también requieres el *pago* y *frecuencia*; sería:

```
SELECT EP.ID_EMPLEADO, EP.NOMBRE, EP.APELLIDO_PATERNO, EP.APELLIDO_MATERNO, 
PE.NOMBRE AS PUESTO, PAG.SUELDO, PAG.FRECUENCIA_PAGO
FROM EMPLEADO EP
INNER JOIN PUESTO_EMPLEADO PE ON PE.id_puesto_empleado = EP.id_puesto;
INNER JOIN PAGO_EMPLEADO PAG ON PAG.ID_EMPLEADO=EP.ID_EMPLEADO
ORDER BY EP.NOMBRE ASC;
```

Conforme a los datos que compartes en la ilustracián de tu esquema de tablas y lo que deseas obtener es lo que te sugiero; considera que el **INNER JOIN** elimina del resultado de la consulta los registros **EMPLEADO** si no hay datos registrados en las otras tablas o al menos en una de ellas (las que sean que intervengan).

A mí me gusta partir de lo general a lo particular con cosas nuevas, ya con la práctica en la mente se tiene claro que hacer con lo que se ve y se sabe debe ser el resultado.

Claro esta agregas el **WHERE** como corresponda y verificando se cumple bien; fijate si *"activo"*, *"Activo"*, *[...]* y *"ACTIVO"* son lo mismo al momento de comparar en la base de datos

Que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Perfecto me sirvió gracias a todos por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente un error que veo es que en la condición **WHERE** esta buscando registros donde el **estado** sea activo, pero en su tabla empleado no veo que tenga el campo estado.

Comment: Si perdón por eso pero la imagen publicada es solo un borrador que hice del diagrama E-R antes de programarlo en MySQL pero le puedo asegurar que todos los campos de la consulta si existen en la base de datos

Comment: Revise si los nombres de los campos de la base de datos son los mismos que colocas en la consulta. En una media hora me desocupo y le colaboro si no ha dado con el error

Comment: si, son los mismos al momento de ejecutar la consulta no me arroja ningún error solo no me muestra resultados. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

no estas tienes las siguientes columnas en el select : pe.id_empleado, e.id_puesto, e.estado, pero si las tienes en los join, intenta hacerlo así:

```
select pe.id_pago_empleado,e.nombre,e.apellido_paterno,e.apellido_materno,pe.sueldo,pe.frecuencia_pago,p.puesto,pe.id_empleado,e.id_puesto,e.estado
from empleado as e inner join pago_empleado as pe on e.id_empleado = pe.id_empleado
inner join puesto_empleado as p on p.id_puesto_empleado = e.id_puesto 
where e.estado = 'Activo' order by e.nombre asc;
```

Comment: Igual funciona si no llamas los id en la consulta, ya lo pude solucionar gracias tenia una columna en null por eso no me arrojaba datos la consulta. Igual gacias por tu tiempo

Comment: No hay problema viejo